# Nginx ignores access_by_lua_file with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I use OpenResty in my project and faced issue that nginx ignores access_by_lua_file when use proxy pass. Here is my code of location:

```
    location /getapi {
                    internal;
                    set $apiauth '';
                    set $api_host '';
                    access_by_lua_file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/lua/getapi.lua;
                    proxy_redirect default;
                    proxy_pass $api_host;
                    proxy_ssl_certificate "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/cert.pem"
certificate_key "cert.key";
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Authorization $apiauth;
                }
```

I call this location with `ngx.location.capture`. In lua file i define variables `apiauth` and `api_host`. But contents of lua file never executes, nginx just ignores it. And no errors in error.log. The only one is that i try to GET empty URL. How can i force nginx to execute contents of `access_by_lua_file`?

Comment: According to the [request execution flow](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2137369/15272097/77d1c09e-1a37-11e6-97ef-d9767035fc3e.png) `access_by_lua` handler should be executed even when you generate response content via the `proxy_pass` directive, but you'd better change it to `rewrite_by_lua` or even better rewrite your code to be used via `set_by_lua` (the last one used somehow different syntax, you must return the value that should be assigned to the variable, check the [examples](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#set_by_lua)).

Comment: @IvanShatsky thanks, ```rewrite_by_lua``` works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @IvanShatsky. Rewrite_by_lua works fo me.